# Trying to parse decimal dstAddr.sin_addr.s_addr from recv() char array

Tags: c, sockets

i am trying to write a small socks proxy as an excercise.

I am trying to parse a SOCKS Connection request from an incoming connection. The socks protocol specifies that the desired destination adress be byte 4,5,6,7 and the desired port be byte 2,3 (byte 0 and 1 are protocol commands). So i want to parse this information to set up an outgoing connection from the proxy and then to pass back and forth the data between the sockets. I am fairly new to C, but i figured i start with something that keeps me interested so bear with me if theres are horrible newbie mistakes :)

The IP-Adress and the Port get calculated incorrectly for border values, typically it is often 254 short. It must be something fairly obvious i am missing but i just don't get it yet :-)

This is the code i currently have:

```
enter code here

void ProxyData(int rcvSocket)
{
char rcvBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE];        
int recvMsgSize;                   
char Socks4Response[] = "\x00\x5a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00";

int dstSocket;
int dstIP;
struct sockaddr_in dstAddr;
int dstPort;

if ((recvMsgSize = recv(rcvSocket, rcvBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE, 0)) < 0)
     perror("recv() failed");
dstIP = (rcvBuffer[4]*16777216)+(rcvBuffer[5]*65536)+(rcvBuffer[6]*256)+rcvBuffer[7];
dstPort = rcvBuffer[2]*256+rcvBuffer[3];
if ((rcvBuffer[0] == 0x04))
     send(rcvSocket, Socks4Response, 9, 0);
if((dstSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
     perror("socket() failed"); 

memset(&dstAddr, 0, sizeof(dstAddr));
dstAddr.sin_family           = AF_INET;
dstAddr.sin_addr.s_addr      = htonl(dstIP);
dstAddr.sin_port             = htons(dstPort);

if (connect(dstSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &dstAddr, sizeof(dstAddr)) < 0 )
     perror("connect() failed");
while (recvMsgSize > 0) 
  { stuff }
close(rcvSocket);
close(dstSocket);
}
```

Comment: Just an advise: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Variables#Magic_numbers

Comment: Another bit of advice: bit shifting is faster and easier to read than multiplying by a power of 256

Comment: @Kshitij: The compiler will almost certainly convert the multiplication to a shift, so it will be no slower.

Answer (score 1):

There's no question in your questions, but assuming you want us to help debug the code.
An issue that jumps out directly is this:

```
char rcvBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE];
...
dstIP = (rcvBuffer[4]*16777216)+(rcvBuffer[5]*65536)+(rcvBuffer[6]*256)+rcvBuffer[7];
```

Most compilers treat char as signed, which means it can be negative. the addition above assumes it's unsigned. You should change it thus.

However, you could just cast it.

```
struct in_addr *dstIP = (struct in_addr*)(rcvBuffer + 4);
```

Now dstIP will be correct and already in network byte order, so no need for htonl:

```
dstAddr.sin_addr = *dstIP;
```

Same with the port, the type is `in_port_t`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `memcpy()` to copy the address and port directly into the `struct sockaddr_in`:

```
dstAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
memcpy(&dstAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, &rcvBuffer[4], 4);
memcpy(&dstAddr.sin_port, &rcvBuffer[2], 2);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this input too :) i am obviously a noob still :)